# How to specify an image to appear in facebook link to your site?

Tags: html, facebook, image

Silly question:  Seeing as how Facebook will automatically sniff out images from a website when somebody links to it, is there any way to give Facebook a hint as to which image you'd prefer be used from your site?  Currently, the logo image that I'd like to appear doesn't even show up in the list that Facebook generates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<link rel="image_src" href="/path/to/image.jpg" / >
```

Answer (score 33):

There is also a new format

```
<head>
    <meta property='og:image' content='http://yoursite.com/INSERT_YOUR_IMAGE.jpg'/>
</head>
```

More details [here](http://rickmanelius.com/article/sharing-facebook-how-improve-your-results-customizing-image-title-and-summary-text) and [here](https://www.newmediadenver.com/blog/using-html-meta-tags-to-tailor-your-story). Also the [facebook share docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) as posted by eliah on this page.

Comment: Be careful about the details, e.g. it doesn't seem to like relative URLs.  You can check your metadata via Facebook's Debug page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/