# Specify facebook image for github.io hosted site

Tags: html, facebook, image, hyperlink

Using the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090179/how-to-specify-an-image-to-appear-in-facebook-link-to-your-site), I've implemented the following approaches to specifying an image to appear on facebook with a link, but it does not appear:

```
<head>
<meta property="og:image" content="lib/divvy.png">
<link rel="image_src" href="lib/divvy.png">
</head>
```

Is there a reason why this wouldn't work with github hosted sites (or a .png file)?  This is the page I'm trying to share:

http://mkfreeman.github.io/divvy/

Comment: Does it work when you provide the fully qualified/absolute path to the image?

Comment: No, i've updated both links on the gh-pages branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the absolute path to the image. You will know if it works when the url path of the image will be displayed as an image on a browser instead of a github blob object.

```
https://github.com/mkfreeman/divvy/blob/master/lib/divvy.png
```

I found out from what Mike has implemented.

```
http://mfviz.com/divvy/lib/divvy.png
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Open Graph Debugger for this:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmkfreeman.github.io%2Fdivvy%2F

It returns:

```
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed  
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. 
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

See also the hints from FB towards Open Graph sharing and optimized distribution here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#tags

Answer (score 0):

Updating to today:

Put the extra HEAD lines of HTML in the file *_includes/custom-head.html* in your github root directory.

The path to a raw image in your repo is:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yourname/reponame/master/path_to_image.jpg

And the debugging url for facebook is now:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/