# How to set image thumbnail when sharing the whole site?

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I have shared the site in messenger and noticed that there is no featured image in the generated box. I know that if i want to share posts i can use WordPress functions like

> the_post_thumbnail()

etc.. But what if i share the whole site ?
p.s i didn't found anything on Google about sharing the whole site.
I think something like this could help:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
the_content();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515833/5842326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SEO yoast plugin and set OG image, description for each post, page etc..

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

https://kb.yoast.com/kb/getting-open-graph-for-your-articles/

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-open-graph-tags-to-wordpress